# Azure AD B2C Error: The client Id specified in the request is not registered in tenant

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to log in to an Azure Active Directory B2C application.

Whenever I access the URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<my_domain>/<my_sign_up_sign_in_policy_name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<my_client_id>...`, I get the following error:

> The client id `<my_client_id>` specified in the request is not registered in tenant `<my_tenant_name>`.

Here is some information about my configuration:

- In `https://portal.azure.com`, I have created the Azure Active Directory B2C tenant which contains the user `globaladmin@<my_domain>.onmicrosoft.com`

  - In order to create the application, I navigated to `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com`, logged in as the global admin and created the "Web Portal v2" application following the [instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-app-registration)
- I granted Web Portal v2 access to Microsoft Graph but did not grant access to Azure AD Windows Graph API (I didn't see this option anywhere)
  [image]
- I can successfully navigate to `https://portal.azure.com` -> Find the Azure AD B2C resource -> Click into it -> Applications. And there is the newly created "Web Portal v2"

[image]

My application has been updated with the new ClientId and ClientSecret of "Web Portal v2". However, when I launch the application and click "Login", I get the error. **What other configuration am I missing?**

Also, I should add that the reason for all of the above configuration is so that I can migrate my application from using Azure AD V1 tokens to Azure AD V2 tokens, which have information in them such as `User.Identity.Name`, which is a value I use to display the currently logged-in user's name in the top right corner of the application. If there is a different/better way to achieve this then please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenant_id>/<policy_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>...` URL is correct, but you shouldn't create an Azure AD B2C application using [the Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/), otherwise it becomes [a faulted app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#faulted-apps) and you then receive the `The client id ... specified in the request is not registered in tenant ...` error.

An Azure AD B2C application should be created using the Azure AD B2C blade of [the Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason for this is that the API Permissions aren't pre-provisioned when you create an app through the AD blade (or Graph API). The way to resolve is to add the API Permissions to the app:

[image: Api Permissions default B2C]

Having just gone through the process of automating this I can tell you that there are four layers that have to be configured for this to work using Graph API (Note: using the beta endpoints).

1. Create application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
2. Update application properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
   a. requiredResourceAccess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/requiredresourceaccess?view=graph-rest-beta
   b. Any other properties, like implicitGrantSettings, logoutUrl, etc
3. Create Service Principal for app just created: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
4. Create oauth2PermissionGrants using the object id of the service principal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to grant admin consent for the Organization registered in the API Permission menu under the manage app setting. It worked for me immediately